# How to change time format in query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I am using the native sql query in Hibernate with the help of AliasToBeanResultTransformer ... as shown below

```
        List<took> uy = (List<took>) session
.createSQLQuery("SELECT distinct u.name, cast('Not Defined' as VARCHAR2(6)) as  BOA_Type, u.updated_by, u.updateddate FROM took u where u.FLAG='N' order by u.name")
        .addScalar("name",Hibernate.STRING)
        .addScalar("Access_Type",Hibernate.STRING)
        .addScalar("updated_by",Hibernate.STRING)
        .addScalar("updateddate",Hibernate.TIMESTAMP)
        .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(took.class)).list();
```

Now the issue is with `addScalar("updateddate",Hibernate.TIMESTAMP)` as on inspecting I have found that all the objects in the list
is having this value

> 2011-01-03 10:10:55.591

but I want that value for this attribute shoulld be in this format ..

> 20110817 17:12

```
(SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm");)
```

Now please advise how can I set in this format itself in the query so that later I don't have to make changes any where else in the code explicitly and my pojo has this property of time stamp please advise

Answer (score 1):

Try this for **Oracle**

```
select to_char(sysdate,'yyyyMMdd HH:mi') from dual
```

To Use this in your query

```
select to_char(yourdatetimefieldname,'yyyyMMdd HH:mi') from yourtablename
```

For **Mysql**, you may this this

```
SELECT date_format(mydatefield,'%Y%m%d %H%i') as mydatefield FROM mytable
```

Comment: Please advise how can I fit this in my query

Comment: on testing it works fine , please advise how can I fit these in my above query

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your query to read in Oracle:

```
SELECT 
  distinct u.name, 
  cast('Not Defined' as VARCHAR2(6)) as BOA_Type, 
  u.updated_by,
  to_char(u.updateddate, 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi') as updated
FROM took u 
where 
  u.FLAG='N' 
order by 
  u.name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9fef46/2

In MySQL, your query will look like this:

```
SELECT 
  distinct u.name, 
  cast('Not Defined' as VARCHAR2(6)) as BOA_Type, 
  u.updated_by,
  date_format(u.updateddate, '%Y%m%d %H%i') as updated
FROM took u 
where 
  u.FLAG='N' 
order by 
  u.name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88fb25/1